# Multiple Instances of Default Producer in Camel created

Tags: apache-camel, producer-consumer

I am using Camel and I have an issue that multiple instances of the Defaultproducer is being created suddenly. Normally when I start the camel route, only one instance of the producer is created as expected. But after running for some time (hours), a new Producer is instantiated. I have no clue how to get around this issue.

Code for doStart of Producer class:

```
@Override
protected void doStart() throws Exception {
    super.doStart();
    connect();
}
```

The connect() is used to connect to the channel using bootstrap. Since a new producer is instantiated, it tries to connect multiple times causing the route to crash sometimes.

```
private void connect() {
    final ChannelFuture channelFuture = bootstrap.connect();
    channelFuture.addListener(new GenericFutureListener<ChannelFuture>() {
        @Override
        public void operationComplete(final ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
            if (!future.isSuccess()) {
                LOG.info("Connection not successful. Cause: " + future.cause().toString() + " -> Reconnecting...");
                reconnect(future.channel());
            } else {
                LOG.info("Connection successful.");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Camel Route:

```
// Define heartbeat routes
    for (final EndpointInfo endpointInfo : endpointInfos) {
        final String uri = BOLD_ENDPOINT_PREFIX + endpointInfo.getUri();
        from("timer:monitor" + uri + "?fixedRate=true&period=" + (heartbeatInterval * 1000))
                .routeId(endpointInfo.getHeartbeatRouteId())
                .autoStartup(false)
                .setBody(constant(HEARTBEAT_MSG))
                .doTry()
                  .to(uri)
                  .process(new HealthProcessor(endpointInfo, true))
                .doCatch(Throwable.class)
                  .process(new HealthProcessor(endpointInfo, false))
                .end();

        uris[index++] = uri;
        routeIds[index] = endpointInfo.getHeartbeatRouteId();
    }

    // Define event route
    from("activemq:Queue.External?cacheLevelName=CACHE_CONSUMER&transacted=true")
            .routeId("eventProcessing")
            .autoStartup(false)
            .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, "Event Received: ${id}")
            .filter(new ConfigEventFilter())
            .filter(videoVerificationEventDisabled)
            .filter(virtualAssistantEventDisabled)
            .filter(eventBatchingDisabled)
            .filter(liveInterventionEventDisabled)
            .process(factory.createProducerTransformer())
            .loadBalance(new BoldLoadBalancer(endpointInfos))
            .to(uris);

    // Set up heartbeat detector
    heartbeatDetector.initialize(this, routeIds);
```

How can a producer be instantiated without it being stopped int eh first place? Do I have to know the state of the service somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Bit confusing , why you have to do all this ? Can you tell what's your use case and what role camel plays ? ;)

Comment: This is a producer consumer application. I am using the camel to define the routes. Currently I am setting up a single endpoint route. The endpoint starts the producer to produce the messages and send it. When a message is delivered to the endpoint I mark this endpoint as healthy. The doStart() starts the producer which tries to connect to the endpoint. The doStart() of producer is called again suddenly after running for a couple of hours. Due to the connect() in doStart() method, it tries to connect again causing redundancy in connections and I am unable to deliver messages to this endpoint.

Comment: Can you post your route ?

Comment: @U2One Could you help me on this?